# ReactJS Martial UI - Autocomplete component getting populated but onclick isn't filtering my table

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-component

i'm still getting use to React.  So here goes.

I have an API that I made which is a list of Countries.  I have the API list being displayed on my webpage in a table.  I have added an autocomplete component from Martial UI and I have been able to get autocomplete component to display my list of Counties too.

What I am trying to do is  - if I type a Country name in and then click the Country name I would like my table to be filter upon that click.

Here is how my webpage looks currently

[image: Here is how my webpage looks currently]

Now here is my code:

[image]

Here is my table code:

[image]

Here is my interface:

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code for your table as that is where you want to do the filering

Comment: Sure thing.  Made an edit on my post

Comment: What component does props.countries come from?

Comment: I have uploaded these now.  Thanks